# Select avg from each table

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql

I would like to query multiple tables and get an average count of `store_key` from each, using a fairly elaborate set of `WHERE` criteria for each.  I can query them all separately, but I'd like to do this in one query.

Each table has `retailer_key`, `store_key` (as well as many other columns)

I would like my query to return something that looks like:

Table Name | AVG # of store keys

Using a where condition similar to `WHERE retailer_key = 41 AND`... Using columns that each of these tables share.

Does that make any sense?  It seems really simple, but for some reason I can't figure out how to build the query.

Comment: which flavor of SQL ? (ie mysql or oracle etc)

Comment: Sounds like it's not normalized to me.

Comment: PLSQL;  My only working way to do this so far is to just write separate queries and separate them by semicolons, and then enter into an excel table, which I realize is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a series of union all operators:

```
SELECT   table_name, AVG(store_key)
FROM     (SELECT 'table1' AS table_name, store_key, retailer_key
          FROM   table1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 'table2' AS table_name, store_key, retailer_key
          FROM   table2
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 'table3' AS table_name, store_key, retailer_key
          FROM   table3
          -- More queries like this if needed...
         ) t
WHERE    retailer_key = 41 -- AND additional conditions
GROUP BY table_name
```

Comment: you would have to select `retailer_key` from each table in order to use it in the where condition of the derived table. Also, it's probably better to put the where conditions and `avg` in the derived table so the db can use indexes

Comment: @FuzzyTree good point about the `retailer_key` - edited. The `avg` cannot be done in the inner queries without duplicating the `where` clause though, which is precisely what the OP was trying to avoid.